# CAShapeLayer strange behavior in the first time animation

Tags: ios, swift3, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation, anchorpoint

I've wrote this animation to the CAShapeLayer (pulseLayer) and in the `viewDidLoad()` :

```
let pulseLayer = CAShapeLayer()
@IBOutlet weak var btnCart: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CategoryViewController.longPressGestureRecognized(_:)))
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)

    heartBeatAnimation.duration       = 0.75
    heartBeatAnimation.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
    heartBeatAnimation.autoreverses   = true
    heartBeatAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
    heartBeatAnimation.toValue        = 1.2
    heartBeatAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

    btnCart.layer.addSublayer(pulseLayer)
}

func addBtnCartLayerWithAnimation() {
    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: btnCart.frame.midX, y: btnCart.frame.midY), radius: btnCart.frame.width * 1.5, startAngle: 0*(CGFloat.pi / 180), endAngle: 360*(CGFloat.pi / 180), clockwise: true)

    pulseLayer.path = ovalPath.cgPath
    pulseLayer.opacity = 0.15
    pulseLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    pulseLayer.bounds = ovalPath.cgPath.boundingBox
    pulseLayer.add(heartBeatAnimation, forKey: "heartBeatAnimation")
    pulseLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
}
```

and the removeLayer function is:

```
func removeLayer() {
    pulseLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    pulseLayer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

The problem is when the first animation of the layer is coming from the bottom of the view !

[the first animation after viewDidLoad](https://media.giphy.com/media/l1J3xim9VbRfPW5ji/giphy.gif)

then after that any invoke for this animation with start from the center(the defined anchor point)

[any animation after the first one](https://media.giphy.com/media/l1J3GsLZWVTx0U824/giphy.gif)

Could anyone tell me why this happening ?

the whole class where I defined and used `UILongGestureRecognizer` on tableView to start/stop the animation :

```
func longPressGestureRecognized(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let longPress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    let state = longPress.state
    let locationInView = longPress.location(in: tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: locationInView)

    switch state {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
        if indexPath != nil {
            addBtnCartLayerWithAnimation()
        }

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
        // some code here not related to the animation 
    default:
        removeLayer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using standalone layers (layers that are not the backing store of a `UIView`), [implicit animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH1-SW4) are added for every animatable property change.

You're seeing this effect because the layer is animating its properties from zero to the initial values you're setting in `addBtnCartLayerWithAnimation()`.

What you want to do is to set these initial values without animation (which needs to be done explicitly). You can wrap the change in a transaction in which you disable animations like so:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

pulseLayer.path = ovalPath.cgPath
pulseLayer.opacity = 0.15
pulseLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
pulseLayer.bounds = ovalPath.cgPath.boundingBox
pulseLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

CATransaction.commit()

pulseLayer.add(heartBeatAnimation, forKey: "heartBeatAnimation")
```

Comment: After I added your code, I've lost the first scaling animation then the scaling animation return on the second and later on!

Comment: You're going to have to show all the code (where/how you start/stop animations, ...)

Comment: I hope this is enough ! :)